# CSLA Project Tracker 4.5.30 - cannot login

Tags: c#, csla

I'm trying to get the 4.5.30 Project Tracker sample working in Visual Studio 2013.  What I'm stuck with is logging in, it doesn't work for me in any of the projects (WfUI, WpfUI or Mvc3UI).

The actual issue is that the call to Membership.ValidateUser() is returning false in ProjectTracker.DalEf.UserDal  - what would cause that?

I can attach to (localdb)\11 and see the aspnetdb database fine in the Server Explorer in Visual Studio and I'm returning data ok from the actual ProjectTracker database as I can see the read only project lists, resource lists, etc.

I can also create and login to new WebApplication projects created from VS2010 and VS2013 fine.

Quick steps to reproduce:  Open the ProjectTracker sample in VS2013, unload the Mvc3UI project, set the WfUI project as the startup project, run it and try and login.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it, and it is a corker.  I thought I had tried everything, but then I checked the databases on (localdb)\v11.0 in SQL Management Studio, and discovered they were readonly... and then the penny dropped.... the samples are installed in Program Files by the 4.5.30 installer.  As soon as I granted the Users group on my PC write full priveleges to the samples directory it all worked fine.

Edit:  Thinking about this logically, the issue must be that the user account SQL Express is running in doesn't have permissions to write to Program Files.

Absolutely no indication of anything like that in the error messages returned by any part of .net of course.  Hopefully the above will save others some pain.

Edit 2:  I have now fully documented everything I did to ProjectTracker running in VS2013 here: http://forums.lhotka.net/forums/t/12200.aspx.